# How can i have aspect oriented programming thing in django python

Tags: python, django, signals

I am using django and i have the very complex matrix of permissions . Suppose i have 10 set of permission groups like

`Permissions = [basic, medium, advanced , very advanced , admin , superadmin , public , etc]`

The other is thing is i have 10 Models and all models have different `view, edit` permissions for each group so in whole the rules becomes in asort of marix of `10 X 10` and more.

I have all the code now in place without permissions. I really don't want to touch the current code at all places for permission checking.

I need the permission checking at following places

The permssions will be based on logged on user permission group

1. In templates where we will show edit,insert,delete button based on permissions
2. In views before showing it , a check is made if user can view/update/delete it

Is there any way that before showing any of the view for `delete,update,insert` the system automatically checks from the permission matrix without writing any code in the view.

Then only thing left will be in the templates that can write if required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are simply looking for the permissions variable which is provided by Django within the templates

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#permissions

```
{% if perms.foo %}
    <p>You have permission to do something in the foo app.</p>
    {% if perms.foo.can_vote %}
        <p>You can vote!</p>
    {% endif %}
    {% if perms.foo.can_drive %}
        <p>You can drive!</p>
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
    <p>You don't have permission to do anything in the foo app.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Example middleware:

```
from django import http

class PermissionMiddleware(object):
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        # you should somehow derive this from the view function and/or view args/kwargs
        your_object = SomeThing.objects.get(...)

        if not request.user.has_perm('name_of_your_object.permission'):
            return http.HttpResponseForbidden()
```

Comment: but how can i check that in view without checking for permission in views. i want to one function defined else where which checks for permssion on every view/edit/upadte/delete things

Comment: This same type of check could be done anywhere, for example, you could add a simple wrapper in the url definitions. As long as you can somehow identify which object will be edited in which view you can always block it. If you really need it global it could even be done in a middleware.

Comment: can you give me example of middleware , how we can do it

Comment: I have added an example, but it's not that useful without further details.

Answer (score 0):

In views, you can use [permission decorators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/)!

They look like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

Or this, for more than a login, i.e. permissions:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required

@permission_required('polls.can_vote')
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

You can also define your own decorators, if you need more complex scenarios (these are the ones I made for myself):

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied


def group_required(*group_names):
    """Requires user membership in at least one of the groups passed in."""

    def in_groups(u):
        if u.is_authenticated:
            if u.groups.filter(name__in=group_names).exists() | u.is_superuser:
                return True
        return False
    return user_passes_test(in_groups)


def superuser_only(function):
    """Limit view to superusers only."""

    def _inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            raise PermissionDenied
        return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return _inner


def has_group(user, group_name):
    return user.groups.filter(name=group_name).exists()
```

...and use them like this:

```
@login_required
@group_required('A', 'B')
def my_view(request):
    ....
```

For use in templates, you can define your own template tags:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def multiply(value, arg):
    return (value * arg)
```